# Python - Table of Values Equation

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a program where you input the Slope, Y-Intercept, the minimum X and maximum X and then it will put a table of values that prints the "y" of each "x" essentially. I know I would have to use a for loop that uses the range function to take the range of the numbers they input so it will display that many items but I'm not sure what to do to make this work.

```
choice4=input("Slope (x): ")
choice5=input("Y-Intercept: ")
choice6=input("Minimum (x): ")
choice7=input("Maximum (x): ")
print("")
for items in range(int(choice6),int(choice7)):
    print ((int(choice4) * x) + int(choice5))
```

Comment: You could probably choose more descriptive variable names!

Comment: Is your maximum value inclusive or exclusive? range will not include its ending argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there. The immediate issue is that you've called your loop variable `items` but then refer to it as `x`.

On a related note, you definitely want to give clearer names to your variables.

There are several smaller issues:

1. `range()` will exclude the final value, so you may need to account for that.
2. Instead of doing the same string-to-int conversions over and over again, you might want to do them just once.

Comment: And `choice7` may need to be +1'd depending on whether it's inclusive

Comment: Thankyou! Its working now and I just put the range of choice7 + 1 and it works :)